# copy data between two dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, copy, iteration

I have two different dataframes, both containing a common element (identifier). I want to copy data from df1 for each identifier in df2 (each identifier can repeat maximum 5 times in df1)

df1 ---data vertically

```
id_column         value1
identifier1       some data1     
identifier1       some data2
identifier1       some data3 
identifier2       some data2 
identifier2       some data1
identifier3       some data3
```

While df2 looks like this and this is how the information should be copied from df1:

df2 ---data horizontally

```
id_column        new1          new2           new3 

identifier1      some data1      some data2       some data3
identifier2      some data2      some data1 
identifier3      some data3
```

Is there a way to do this with python?

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand, but if you want to convert df1 into df2, you can use:

```
df1.pivot(index='id',columns='value1')
```

Comment: thk you so much, unfortunately since index contains duplicate entries, I can't use it. I have also updated initial request since the columns name in df2 is different

Comment: So I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. is it just converting df1 into df2?

Comment: just pasting the correspondent information from df1 to df2, using the common identifier but horizontally because the data in df1 is vertically(excepting column 'id' which is in the same format).